# Installing Definitely Typed packages in VS 2015 RC AspNet5 using Gulp and TSD

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gulp, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to install angular.d.ts in my MVC6 application and am running into major headaches.

I have set up Gulp to "REINSTALL" any packages I need using tsd, but I cannot figure out how to get the packages installed in the first place.  All the instructions tell me to run tsd install xxx or some such but I cannot get Windows to recognize it.  I realize I can add it to my path etc.  But everyone seems to think I can just run it.  Is there some trick I never learned in VS in regards to this?

Comment: Have you installed tsd globally? `npm install -g tsd`

Comment: Was wondering about that later while doing something else.  Should have known.  I guess I was expecting something within the project/solution environment.  I imagine something will come along and fill that void in the future.  If you want to write it into an answer, I will mark it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should either:

1. Install tsd globally: `npm install -g tsd`.

or

2. Use local executable: `./node_modules/.bin/tsd`.